# Customization/Hiding Of Parameters in WSO2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have services that takes parameters as given below

```
> <book category="cooking">
> <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
> <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author> <year>2005</year>
> <price>30.00</price> </book>
```

Now i want to hide  parameters and i want my client should only see

```
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
</book>
```

how can is it possible in WSO2 ESB.
Any help would be so helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to hide some parameters to the client or consumer so that they will not have to pass them as part of their **request**. for instance, "price" element in your case.

Well, you can create the proxy as **wsdl-based proxy** with the appropriate wsdl file such that you don't have the "price" element in the request or in the respective complex type. Now, the clients will not be able see the "price" element in the request because you are describing the WSDL contract without "price" element.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Dear Praveen, i want price should be hard coded and client should not know about "price" value, Client will have to pass all parameters to SOAP message but  few parameters will filled from the Clients other will be auto filled or Hard coded client would not see that .Before ESB i used to write wrapper services for this kind of Requirement but i have switched to ESB i am finding the solution but i am failed to achieve that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. You can use payload mediator, transform it via xslt, do it in script mediator etc. I think for your case I'd use payload mediator or xslt. After you've done payload/xslt you can send back the transfomrmed payload to your caller. You can find a lot of examples on the wso2 page.

e.g. here

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Martin Hald.Can you be more specific, I am new bee to WSO2 ESB , and  i have trying since almost two weeks trying to Find out the solution for it. My requirement is so simple i have some kind of web services and every services have more than Ten to twelve parameters and i want to hide them, i want my consumers of services only see few parameters. Any kind of help would so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With a JS Mediator, you can do this:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <book category="cooking">
            <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
            <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author> 
            <year>2005</year>
            <price>30.00</price> 
        </book>
    </format>
    <args/>
</payloadFactory>

<log level="full"/>
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
    var msg = mc.getPayloadXML();
    mc.setPayloadXML(
        <book category="cooking">
            <title lang="en">{msg..*::title}</title>
            <author>{msg..*::author}</author> 
            <year>{msg..*::year}</year>
        </book>
    );
]]>
</script>
<log level="full"/>
```

The payloadFactory mediation above is just to define the XML you proposed in your question.

Additionally, you can use the payloadFactory mediator:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <book category="cooking">
            <title lang="en">$1</title>
            <author>$2</author> 
            <year>$3</year>
        </book>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//book/title/text()"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//book/author/text()"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//book/year/text()"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Finally, for the XSLT approach, you can define a local-entry file in the synapse-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="xsltToTransform" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="price"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
</localEntry>
```

Then, in the mediation sequence, just invoke the defined local entry.

```
<xslt key="xsltToTransform"/>
```